# Using regex in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I want to extract 2 parts of certain string. For this I want to use regular expressions.
For Example the String is: Big_Dog_0044_0080 and my Regex is: Big_Dog_([0-9]+)_?([0-9A-Z]*)
Group 1 would be then 0044 and the second would be 0080.

Now my problem is to bring this into an select statement:
I tried it with regex_substr.

This was my result:

```
 select 
'Big_Dog_0044_0080' as TestString,
regexp_substr('Big_Dog_0044_0080', '([0-9]+)') Group1 , 
regexp_substr('Big_Dog_0044_0080', '([0-9A-Z]*)') Group2 from dual;
```

My Output:

```
TESTSTRING         Group1 Group2
Big_Dog_0044_0080   0044    B
```

First of all Group 2 is wrong i would expect 0080.
What I am doing wrong here?

And second question, any other way to solve this?
I have like 5-6 different regexp I want to use. For example next one would be
([A-C])_CatWeezle

I mean like select the input string column and go through the possible regexp.
If one regexp matches, then stop and extract values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am doing wrong here?

The regular expression `'([0-9A-Z]*)'` will match the first occurrence of zero-or-more digit or upper-case alphabetic characters in the string. For your string `'Big_Dog_0044_0080'` the first character is the upper-case alphabetic character `B` so that will get matched and the second character `i` does not match your regular expression so it is not included in the group.

You state that your string matches the pattern:

```
Big_Dog_([0-9]+)_?([0-9A-Z]*)
```

Then you can anchor the pattern to the end of the string using `$` and can use:

```sql
WITH test_data (value) AS (
  SELECT 'Big_Dog_0044_0080' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Big_Dog_00440080' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Big_Dog_00440A80' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '([0-9]+)_?([0-9A-Z]*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS Group1 , 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '([0-9]+)_?([0-9A-Z]*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 2) AS Group2
FROM   test_data;
```

Which outputs:

> | VALUE | GROUP1 | GROUP2 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Big_Dog_0044_0080 | 0044 | 0080 |
> | Big_Dog_00440080 | 00440080 |  |
> | Big_Dog_00440A80 | 00440 | A80 |

*(Note: the second row is matched entirely by the first group and the second group has zero-width and the third row will match the first group until it finds a non-digit character and then start the second group.)*

If the delimiting underscore is optional then you may want to use fixed-width matches (assuming the substrings are each 4-characters):

```
WITH test_data (value) AS (
  SELECT 'Big_Dog_0044_0080' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Big_Dog_00440080' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Big_Dog_00440A80' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '([0-9]{4})_?([0-9A-Z]{4})$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS Group1 , 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '([0-9]{4})_?([0-9A-Z]{4})$', 1, 1, NULL, 2) AS Group2
FROM   test_data;
```

Which outputs:

> | VALUE | GROUP1 | GROUP2 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Big_Dog_0044_0080 | 0044 | 0080 |
> | Big_Dog_00440080 | 0044 | 0080 |
> | Big_Dog_00440A80 | 0044 | 0A80 |

> I mean like select the input string column and go through the possible regexp. If one regexp matches, then stop and extract values.

Use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
WITH test_data (value) AS (
  SELECT 'Big_Dog_0044_0080' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Big_Dog_00440080' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Big_Dog_00440A80' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A_CatWeezle' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT value,
       CASE
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(value, '^Big_Dog_(\d{4})_?([0-9A-Z]{4})$')
       THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '^Big_Dog_(\d{4})_?([0-9A-Z]{4})$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(value, '^([A-C])_CatWeezle$')
       THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '^([A-C])_CatWeezle$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
       END AS group1,
       CASE
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(value, '^Big_Dog_(\d{4})_?([0-9A-Z]{4})$')
       THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '^Big_Dog_(\d{4})_?([0-9A-Z]{4})$', 1, 1, NULL, 2)
       END AS group2
FROM   test_data;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | GROUP1 | GROUP2 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Big_Dog_0044_0080 | 0044 | 0080 |
> | Big_Dog_00440080 | 0044 | 0080 |
> | Big_Dog_00440A80 | 0044 | 0A80 |
> | A_CatWeezle | A |  |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=afb9dbf6ddc01cd5f8fe1aab6ab2a3fd)*

Comment: thank you so much! That was exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the question is easy:

```
SQL> SELECT 'Big_Dog_0044_0080' AS TestString,
  2         REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Big_Dog_0044_0080', '\d+', 1, 1) Group1,
  3         REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Big_Dog_0044_0080', '\d+', 1, 2) Group2
  4    FROM DUAL;

TESTSTRING        GROU GROU
----------------- ---- ----
Big_Dog_0044_0080 0044 0080

SQL>
```

I don't quite understand what you meant to say by the *CatWeezle* thing.